# Scala build tool and test framework that play nice together?

Tags: testing, scala, ant, sbt

Here are my goals:
1. Run my tests in Eclipse and see the pretty green or red bar.
2. Run my tests on the command line with a build tool.

I'm leaning towards specs and sbt, but I can't get them to work. I have no desire to pick up Maven. My question is which one of the follow sets works best?

1. sbt and scalatest
2. sbt and specs
3. ant and scalatest
4. ant and specs
5. something else?

A consideration is how much effort do other people need to get the project up and running on a new machine. Bonus points if it can integrate with Hudson.

Comment: What problems do you have with sbt and specs?

Comment: I eventually tracked it down to a bug in sbt that it only runs tests defined as objects, not classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SBT is definitely the way to go over ant. Ant will not give you congruency with maven project structures and would force you to roll your own dependency management.

Either scalatest or specs will work. The former seems to be a de facto, but I get excellent results with specs.

I am not an Eclipse user, but would be surprised if either test library was not supported.

Comment: Another vote for SBT. Love it, it makes Maven/Ant seem so ugly and inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently switching the specs project to sbt and fixing a few things with Mark Harrah (check out the [sbt mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/simple-build-tool/browse_thread/thread/9432c3dbd972f2bd) for the details).

Please post any issues you may have with specs and sbt and I'll try to fix them ASAP.

Thanks,

Eric.